# Extract the discriminating rows of two dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, extract, difference

I have two dataframes structured like this:

```
X A  B  C SUM
E 1  0  1  2
F 0  0  1  1
G 1  1  0  2
```

and this:

```
X A  B  C SUM
E 1  0  1  2
F 0  0  1  1
G 1  1  0  2
H 0  0  1  1
I 0  0  0  0
```

The result that i want to obtain is:

```
 X A  B  C   
 H 0  0  1
```

So, i want a code which is able to create another dataframe **made by only those rows which are not present in both dataframes**. Moreover, the sum of these rows has to be **more than zero**.

Could someone help me?
Thank You!

Comment: Maybe `dplyr::anti_join`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution to your question.
Let the two data-sets be `mydata1` and `mydata2`

```
require(dplyr)
rbind(anti_join(mydata1 %>% filter(SUM > 0), mydata2 %>% filter(SUM > 0), by = colnames(mydata1)), 
      anti_join(mydata2 %>% filter(SUM > 0), mydata1 %>% filter(SUM > 0), by = colnames(mydata1)))
```

Based on the comment, there's one thing you can do is make sure the columns are same.

```
require(dplyr)
common_columns <- intersect(colnames(mydata1), colnames(mydata2))
rbind(anti_join(mydata1 %>% filter(SUM > 0), mydata2 %>% filter(SUM > 0), by = common_columns), 
      anti_join(mydata2 %>% filter(SUM > 0), mydata1 %>% filter(SUM > 0), by = common_columns))
```

Comment: Yeah, it works perfectly. The problem is that the two dataframe haven't always got the same columns. So i would like to extract the different rows and columns too. How could i do, simply modifying that code?

Comment: @Silvia Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
require(data.table)
dat1 <- data.table(X = c("E","F","G"), A = c(1,0,1), B = c(0,0,1), C = c(1,1,0), SUM = c(2,1,2))
dat2 <- data.table(X = c("E","F","G","H","I"), A = c(1,0,1,0,0),  B = c(0,0,1,0,0), C = c(1,1,0,1,0),
               SUM = c(2,1,2,1,0))

dat3 <- rbind(dat1[,!(names(dat1) %in% "SUM"), with = FALSE], dat2[,!(names(dat2) %in% "SUM"), with = FALSE])

dat3[duplicated(dat3)==FALSE & duplicated(dat3, fromLast = TRUE)==FALSE & 
   rowSums(dat3[,!(names(dat3) %in% "X"), with = FALSE])>0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
dat1 <- data.table(X = c("E","F","G"), A = c(1,0,1), B = c(0,0,1), C = c(1,1,0), SUM = c(2,1,2))
dat2 <- data.table(X = c("E","F","G","H","I"), A = c(1,0,1,0,0),  B = c(0,0,1,0,0), C = c(1,1,0,1,0),
                   SUM = c(2,1,2,1,0))


D1=dat1[!dat1$X%in%dat2$X,]
D2=dat2[!dat2$X%in%dat1$X,]
DF=rbind(D1,D2)
DF=DF[DF$SUM>0,]
DF$SUM=NULL
```